# How can i use JavaScript to view an element in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can use JavaScript to view an element in fullscreen mode.

i have probleme with firefox mozilla web browser

```
function openFullscreen(elem) {
 if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
 elem.requestFullscreen();
 } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
 elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
 } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
 elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
 } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
 elem.msRequestFullscreen();
 }
}
```

when i call requestFullscreen() method on an element i have an error on console log telling me

> Request for fullscreen was denied because at least one of the document’s containing elements is not an iframe or does not have an “allowfullscreen” attribute.

you have to know that I want to make this action ( full screen ) on a  element

Answer (score 0):

To check if browser supports full screen use the `fullscreenEnabled` attribute, a part from Document interface.

```
if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
    // supported
}
```

To improve the user experience make your app listen for errors.

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenerror", function (event) {
    // an error occurred
});
```

The correct syntax is :

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
```